# How can I build AST from Scala code?

Tags: scala, compilation

How can I turn scala program into AST and operate with it programatically, from java/scala?

Comment: Are you talking about [AST (abstract syntax tree)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree)?

Comment: Yes, I am. Sorry I got the title wrong.

Comment: Take a look at [scala reflection API](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/symbols-trees-types.html) -- it allows you to manipulate with scala as AST (trees section in particular)

Comment: Is the program already compiled? In the source code, you can inject a macro to get hold of the corresponding AST of some expression.

Comment: It's source code. I know little about the macro. Could you please show me some examples? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can parse scala program source code.

Take a look to parboiled2 PEG parser. As an examle it have scala parser implementation

https://github.com/sirthias/parboiled2/tree/master/scalaParser/src/main/scala/scalaparser

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but you can have a look at scalameta :

https://scalameta.org/

> Library to read, analyze, transform and generate Scala programs